# Associate every row in table A with a row in table B, wrapping around

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to create a table with combinations of data in two other tables. Say table ONE looks like this:

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

And table TWO looks like this:

```
X
Y
Z
```

What I want is not a cross join, or anything, I just want A and B together, and when B runs out of rows, to just repeat, so the output (table THREE) looks like this:

```
A X
B Y
C Z
D X
E Y
F Z
```

I don't want to add or remove any rows. The end result should have the exact same number of rows as in table ONE. If it makes it easier, the number of rows in table ONE is always a perfect multiple of the number of rows in table TWO, so I don't have to worry about partial matches. If table ONE had 12 rows, then table TWO would be repeated 4 times instead of just 2, and the result will still be 12 rows.

Comment: Are both tables ordered by their single column?

Comment: Yes, but really there's no order, as I should be able to "order by" the first column, and get effectively the results in table THREE (each row in table TWO appears associated with a row in table ONE, the same number of times ... in the example, two times).

Comment: So ( `A`, `Y` ); ( `B`, `X` ); ( `C`, `Z` ) repeated twice is an acceptable result? Without an explicit order a table is just a collection of rows. And the number of rows in table `TWO` is always exactly twice the number of rows in table `ONE`. Perfect every time.

Comment: No, the order matters in that every row in Table ONE should be there exactly once. So you'll have (A, X), (B, Y), (C, Z), (D, X), (E, Y), and (F, Z). The number rows in Table ONE is always an exact multiple of the number or rows in table TWO, however, the solution before doesn't require that, as it'll just modulo table TWO over the ordered rows in table ONE, and that works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use modulo arithmetic:

```
select o.*, t.*
from (select o.*, row_number() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from one o
     ) o join
     (select t.*, row_number() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum,
             count(*) over () as cnt
      from two
     ) t
     on (o.seqnum - 1) % cnt = t.seqnum - 1
```

This adds an enumerated value to each table.  It then uses modulo arithmetic to match the rows.

Comment: I used an appropriate ORDER BY instead of the (select null).

Comment: nice answer, I was able to replicate this too, but I don't understand how does the % change everything.